# Periodic task in kernel module Rpi

Tags: linux, module, kernel, raspberry-pi

I currently developing a gpio based kernel module for a custom protocol. as per requirements of protocol, i have to send data, clock and enable signal to output device throgh gpio. this data is 16-bit. for sending any new data the enable signal first goes high. then, data is sent 1 by 1 bit, at every negative edge(High to low) of clock. after sending all 16-bits, the clock signal is stopped and enable signal goes low.

i have successfully developed this protocol with FriendlyARM mini2440. At that time i have used one of timers and setup its irq. in its service routine, i have sent the data 1 by 1 bit.

I am currently doing same thing in Raspberry pi. I have read the Datasheet of BCM2825 and it says it has 4 system timers. but, seaching through the Rpi-forums, i found that Rpi uses system timer 0,2 and 3. so, only one sytem timer 1 is remaining which i want to utilize. i could not figure out how to setup system timer on Rpi. has any one used it in kernel module? then please help.

instead of writing kernel module, if i would patch linux kernel with xenomai patches, would it be easy task to setup a periodic timer and send data through it timer interrupt routine?

Any Suggestions? Thanks in advance.